# Help for identifying an oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm trying to identify an oscilloscope used for anything related to power management, cellular, and chips. Here are two pictures of the oscilloscope. [image]

[image: Images of the oscilloscopes used by Apple for what I listed above]

Comment: Huh? The first picture doesn't look like an oscilloscope.  The second picture looks like there might be 3 oscilloscopes.  What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: @JohnD I don't know exactly what type of material it is, but I'd like to have the name of the model of the hardware used on the first picture and on the second one on the  top right on the desk. But I'm only asking this out of curiosity, so that's why I have no clue if this is an oscilloscope.

Comment: I would suggest Rohde & Schwarz. The color sheme seems familiar.

Comment: In the bottom picture on the desk on the right, the big black thing on the left side of the desk is the oscilloscope. The big white thing sitting on the right of the desk doesn't look like an oscilloscope. Might be a VNA or spectrum analyzer.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know @DKNguyen

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent searched it and looks very much like one from this brand, thanks

Comment: In the second picture I see a LeCroy scope, a Tektronix scope or spectrum analyzer and possibly a Rhode & Schwartz scope or spectrum analyzer, hard to tell.

Comment: Wow great knowledge, thanks ! How are these things used and what's the difference between the scope and spectrum analyser ? @JohnD

Comment: A oscilloscope's FFT function if it has one, leaves a lot to be desired. A spectrum analyzer does one thing with much more resolution over a much wider bandwidth.

Comment: Really interesting stuff... I actually wanna start to learn more about electronics

Answer (score 1):

It is this:

Rohde-Schwarz FSVR Real-time spectrum analyzer:

[image]
https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/products/test-and-measurement/benchtop-analyzers/rs-fsvr-real-time-spectrum-analyzer_63493-11047.html

Comment: What would be the rough price for this ? I can't find anything but quotes on internet.

Comment: At least $20kUSD

Comment: damn ! that's huge

Comment: Yep. R&S stuff is expensive. Even their oscilloscope is like $5k. Spectrum analyzers are specialty equipment. Oscilloscopes aren't really so start at much lower prices, although they easily get up to $20k as well. I have one next to me, and you know what? The probes for it cost more than the oscilloscope.

Comment: well that's not surprising, this is the stuff Apple uses so I didn't expect less from them...

Comment: @Kwiky Forget Apple. The defense industry.

Comment: Hahaha alright ! @DKNguyen